# Enterprise Server WCF Stress/Harness Testing

Tags: .net, performance, wcf, http, stress-testing

I am writing in order to ask a question on WCF performance.

**1. Background**

We have a client-server system that runs on .NET 3.5. The server is a *C# service* and the client is a *silverlight app*.

I have written a stress tester that is a winforms app and works like that:

- It spawns worker processes
- The worker processes fire different
  stress loads `[eg for (i=0;i<100;i++)
  Send(payload)]`
- The service is running as
  `[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode
  =InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single)]`.
- All the timeouts (operation, send
  receive,..) have been set to maximum
- `serviceThrottling:
  maxConcurrentSessions="200"`
- message tracing is enabled and prints
  everything

**2. The Issue**

After some thresholds(dependent on the stress test loads and the environment under test) my worker processes (normal .NET 3.5 C# console apps) begin to throw exceptions. I was getting timeoutExceptions initially but after a lot of read & tweak sessions I got to a point where I get only two exceptions (only under very high load)

- *The underlying connection was closed:
  A connection that was expected to be
  kept alive was closed by the server.*
- *An error occurred while receiving the
  HTTP response to . This could be due
  to the service endpoint binding not
  using the HTTP protocol. This could
  also be due to an HTTP request
  context being aborted by the server
  (possibly due to the service shutting
  down). See server logs for more
  details.*

Alongside with that I can see substantial message loss. The server never fails(which is good). I think the server is simply rejecting messages it cannot handle.

**3. Actions Taken**

I have read **a lot** of articles and tweaked a lot of parameters(including throttling, timeouts, etc). For example I have tried all of the sugggestions here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/WCFThrottling.aspx

I do get performance improvement but depending on what environment I am running the server I will hit this upper limit and start having messages rejected.

No errors at all are reported in the trace logs

**4. Ideally...**

...I would want to have a server that gets slower as load increases, but does not miss messages. (ie its ok if a client takes 10 secs to get a reply if 500 others are using the service)

**Is this possible under WCF over Http and a single-threaded, single context servive? Am I missing a setting here or am I hitting an upper bound and getting the expected WCF behaviour?**

NB: I have tried using `ConcurrencyMode.Multiple`. I do get an improvement (ie more load is needed to hit the upper bound) but I do hit the same exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I 'found' my answer!

I will explain here what I did in case someone else bumps into this one.

First of all you can check the  *Calls Oustanding counter*, which is something like a T*CP backlog*.

In addition in *perfmon* can see how many calls are being handled concurrently, and how many are queued.

These two indicators allowed me to validate that indeed I was hitting the roof. Therefore I needed code that would send/rcv some ACKs upon messaging. Luckily MS have already done this for us! Its called ***reliable WCF messaging***.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730123.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480191.aspx

By implementing a WsHttpBinding the server could cope under loads where it previously failed. In addition the server managed to cope with loads twice as much as before.

Clearly there is a performance overhead but it is indeed reliable.

Great, so I guess that now that I found the solution I can tell to the users that all of that fantastic stuff is out there, but they ain't gonna get nothing of this because their client runs on silverlight 3 which does not have reliable WCF implementations...yey!

Answer (score 1):

Your best option would be to use the [netMsmqBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.netmsmqbinding.aspx). [Here is an overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789048.aspx) of how it works if you're not familiar. This binding will allow your service to queue the excess load using MSMQ, so that messages will not be lost. This should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This should also fix my issue. But like the reliable binding options this is also not in Silverlight 3 ..

Comment: I've not tried this, but you could have your Silverlight client call a WCF Routing Service using basicHttpBinding, then have your routing service route the call to actual service using netMsmqBinding. In theory that might work. I've used routing services with Silverlight before and it works great. Something to try anyways.

Comment: Interesting idea, thanks! The only quirk I can think of with this is if the Routing Service is not load balanced correctly => we end up flooding this one before getting to the Q.

Comment: It's possible, but I don't think the routing service hangs on to the worker thread waiting for the response to come back from the target, so you should have much better scalability with this approach. Give it a try, I suspect it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a particular reason why you have to run a singleton service? Unless you want to share some state with all your services I would avoid it altogether. The problem with singleton is that its state can be changed by any of multiple worker threads connected to it, so it must synchronise access to avoid state corruption. This is rather expensive and ensures that only one client can access the singleton at a time.

Prefer to use per-call, or session if you need to maintain state across multiple requests.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Well the reason why I am using a singleton is something beyond my control. This configuration has been signed off as the release one and hence changing this cannot be done. 

What i need to reason upon now is whether message loss is unavoidable at peak loads...

Comment: @Gioros: Well in that case I'm afraid you might be stuck with it. Your change request should include descriptions of the singleton behaviour, and comparisons to other instance management configurations. Juval Lowy has some good msdn articles and books for your references. Good luck, i'd be interested to hear what design decisions caused you to use singleton configuration.

Comment: I'd be interested myself :-) I guess though that the reason was reliability since no multi-threaded callbacks(=> less multi-threaded headaches) would be involved..

Answer (score 0):

You should also try truning ASP.NET Threapool configuration: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/821268 as Service is hosted under IIS.

Regards,
Amit Bhatia

Comment: Thanks for the answer Amit. The WCF service is hosted under a custom windows service && !IIS. 

Plus doesn't <code>(InstanceContextMode =InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single)</code> imply that there is only one thread for everything?